# Can't access mounted partition in Fedora 38

Tags: fedora, mount, disk

**TLDR;** Fedora38 (i3wm spin) installed on 256gb nvme. Second internal disk has 'backup' btrfs partition. I can only access the mounted partition as `sudo`. How do I properly mount the partition on boot so that I can read/write without root/sudo?

--

I have a i3wm Fedora38 install. I'm booting from the 256 nvme & have a 262gb 'backup' btrfs partition.

I setup the mount in gnome-disks & have rebooted. I try to access the Backup partition through nautilus, and get 'Don't have permission to access the requested location'.

If i `ls -la /mnt/` it shows me the permissions are `drwx------. 1 root root`.

If I run gnome-disks withOUT sudo, I'm unable to edit mount options or even mount the partition. If I mount manually through `sudo gnome-disks` I can't access the disk either.

In the past (Fedora 36), when I setup mount through `gnome-disks` I was able to access it no problem.

Previously, when this partition was exFat I tried `sudo chown mygroup:myuser`, it would fail to chown. And similarly it was not accessible by me, but a sudo terminal or sudo nautilus could get in.

I also just don't think I should have to chown or change permissions on the disk? I don't know. I don't want to break anything.

[image: gnome-disks panel]

Comment: Is it mounted "Read Only" (`ro`)? Use `mount` to see. Read `man mount`. There should be a section on mounting `btrfs` volumes. Try something like `sudo mount -o remount,rw ...`. Read `man fsck fsck.btrfs`.

Comment: No, it's rw. & I can both read & write to it from a sudo nautilus. `mount` shows `(rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/,x-gvfs-show)`. I'll check out the fsck & try the remount you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with permission.

```
drwx------. 1 root root
```

means the folder can only be accessed by `root`, so if it's your own PC, I think

```shell
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/ -R
```

may work (but it's not so safe, however it's fast).

If that fails, you can try `su` to change to `root` user first, then run the command.

You may also need to run `chown` with `-R` ,the `-R` option means **recursive**.